# How can I get the string if first character matches the given character value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried for match last character

Here i am passing the One character like A or B, it returns the string ends with passing Character

```
var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
return name.match( /A$/i );
```

Comment: In your regex pattern, `$` stands to the end of the string, the anchor you are looking for is `^` which stands to the start of the string: `val = /^A/i.test(val) ? val : '';`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand the question correctly buy I suppose you are trying to achieve the following:

```
'monkey cow lion'.match(/^m.*$/)
Array[ "monkey cow lion" ]
```

Which will give you the entire string in case it matches.

If you are just looking for the word, I think you can go with:

```
'monkey cow lion'.match(/^m\w+/)
Array [ "monkey" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to test if the string starts with a particular letter

You can do following:

```
name.charAt(0) === 'A' ? name : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the `/g` instead of `/i`.

I guess is is what you're looking for : http://regexr.com/3g74s

So in your JS it will look like this : `text.match(/\b[Aa]\w*\b/g);` where `[Aa]` is the letters you're looking for.

Or before test match you can lowercase or uppercase the string to test.

If you want to force the string length to be longer than 1 char, you can add `{1,}` as the following example : http://regexr.com/3g74v .

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to use Javascript native (ECMAScript 6) ***startsWith()*** function.
It accepts two parameters:

```
string.startsWith(searchvalue, start)
```

1. **First** is the string you want to search.
2. **Second** one is optional and represents at which position to start the search.

so this must work (.toupperCase used to make it case insensitive):

```
return (name.toUpperCase().startsWith("A".toUpperCase())) ? name : null;
```

if you need to be case sensitive remove them:

```
return (name.startsWith("A")) ? name : null;
```